# path on ASM for standby database after switchover

Tags: oracle, standby

The question is quite complicated for me to describe so please be patient and ask for  more details of needed.

I have a primary database (ABC) and a standby one (STBABC). Both are located on ASM. For both primary and standby there are several parameter in spfile (control_files, db_create_file_dest, db_recovery_file_dest  etc. ) to point where files has to be located. For ASM databases value is always something like +DATA or +ARCH  without full path.  Instance creates automaticaly full path which is more or less something like : +DATA/<DB_UNIQUE_NAME>/ARCHIVELOG  or +ARCH/<DB_UNIQUE_NAME>/ARCHIVELOG  and so on.
Every thing is ok until .... I switchover databases .  Then name of ex standby (which is now primary)is ABC but all files are still located in STBABC directory.  Is there any easy way to replace old directory name ( STBABC)  to ABC ?

regards
K.

Comment: NO, and why would you?  You have switched the role of the database, but it's name and the location of its files has not changed.  Nor should they.

Comment: Switcover in fact is the way of fast migration of primary db.  It would me more "elegant" and clear to have directories with the same name as database name . That is the main and only reason  :)

Comment: But the switchover doesn't change the _name_ of the database, either ...

Comment: it doesn't but in the path oracle uses db_unique_name instead of db_name.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used DG, but I can't imagine either db_name or db_unique name being changed simply because of a status change. In any event, the files are physically where they are.You could hardly do a "fast" failover if it had to relocate all the files into different directories.

Comment: no doubt - you are absolutely right.  So probably in meantime I will do all changes/moves manually. Thanks for your time and discussion :).

Comment: so what is your problem? You want to migrate your database to different server and want the same file paths on the new server as on the old one?

Comment: i knew it would be problematic to explain :).  Yes it is my problem - the new database , after migration using DG, is in directory with name of standby_db which could be confusing for other administrators ( at least this name won't be used anywhere, anymore). I was aware of moving all files to directory of +DATA\db_name instead of +DATA\db_unique_name after migration but it takes a time and could generates mistakes.  That is why I asked this question .. to find another, smarter way to achieve it.